# Принудительная остановка скрипта  php [решен]

Tags: php

Наткнулся на такой момент интересный:

У меня есть скрипт, который выпоняется более 10 минут, скажем это бот, который обходит сайт и смотрит, что по чем.

Построен на рекурсии. Теперь заметил вот такой момент. Я запускаю скрипт, он работает, работает, пишет статистику в файл и тут я решил его остановить.

2 клавишей мыши по браузеру, остановить. Хорошо скрипт остановлен.

Однако он как-то все равно продолжает работать в фоне, допиливает мне статистику.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит, почему я остановил скрипт, а он продолжает работать (при этом само окно браузера уже ничего не грузит)

Comment: давай сюда этот скриптец))

Comment: Можно влепить где-нибудь какой-нибудь "флаг", например, создавать в папке со скриптом файл определенный, а в скрипте проверять наличие такого файла, и делать принудительную остановку, если файл имеется. Сам файл ложить в папку, например, переходом по специальному URL

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223, опубликуйте Ваше решение, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

За прерывание работы скрипта при отключении клиента отвечает [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Также в цикле можно проверять, отключился ли пользователь, функцией [`connection_aborted()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.connection-aborted.php)

З.Ы. Обратите внимание на [`flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.flush.php) при использовании этих методов.

Comment: Это не сработает, если рекурсивно был вызван скрипт средствами PHP, я тоже так когда-то писал бота, чтобы обойти ограничение 30 секунд на хостинге.  
Скрипт просто в конце своей работы (я делал когда он выполняется уже 25 секунд) делает так:  

    file_get_contents("себя.php?данные_для_продолжения_работы");
P.S. А через месяц меня забанил хостер за слишком большую создаваемую нагрузку (халявный хост).  
P.P.S. А вот останавливал как раз таки файликом.

Comment: А в условии и не говорится о рекурсии ;-)

А ваш пример с file_get_contents() - это, по факту, handle. Тоже самое, что попытаться получить страницу по определенному URL и не дожидаться ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Дык браузер всего-то ждёт ответа от веб-сервера и остановка загрузки страницы никаким образом не останавливает процесс на сервере

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли остановить выполнение скрипта, если мы тыкаем кнопочку стоп в браузере ?

Comment: Нет. В принципе никак..  Скрипт остановится только тогда, когда выполнится, или по таймауту (обычно 30 секунд).

При нажатии на кнопку "Стоп" в браузере ты просто говоришь этому браузеру, чтобы он не ждал ответа от сервера

Comment: А вот если к примеру у нас парсер сайта, открытый для всхе клиентов. 

И так 100 троллей заходят запускают там словарь какой-то на 1000000 страниц и уходят. И наш сервер честно 100 раз отрабатывает. Это де очень большая нагрузка на сервер, есть ли от этого лекарства ? 

Я что то слышал про то, что есть функция php, если связь с клиентом потеряна, то можно остановится. Сойдет ли это дело для моего вопроса ?

Comment: Нет такой функции.
Такое можно только на самом сервере настроить, и то не так просто, как кажется.
Самый простой способ: не давать доступ к таким скриптам и запускать их по крону (cron)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен